# Where to find old (.msi) version of mono?

Tags: mono, download

Where to find old version of mono (specifically 2.6.1), in binary format, for windows 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mono project provides [archive with the previous releases](http://download.mono-project.com/archive/) which contains also [mono-2.6.1-gtksharp-2.12.9-win32-1.exe](http://download.mono-project.com/archive/2.6.1/windows-installer/1/mono-2.6.1-gtksharp-2.12.9-win32-1.exe).